# AWT Robot class constructor error

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, awtrobot

I try to make an Image Puzzle on Eclipse.

While I'm launching and testing(1) my code, there is some error occurred on robot class constructor in `PzImage` class. I try to fix, but I don't know why that error occurred and No suggestion on eclipse.

This is whole code.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class KDHS {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PzImage watch = new PzImage("C:\\Users\\rlaeh\\Desktop\\김동혁\\JAVA_workspace\\watch.jpg");
    }   
}

class PzImage {

    int wid, hei;
    ImageIcon img;
    ImageIcon [][] piece = new ImageIcon[5][5];
    Dimension dim;
    Robot robot = new Robot(); //under line at "new Robot();"
    JFrame frm = new JFrame("seperating");

    protected PzImage(String img_path) {
        img = new ImageIcon(img_path);
        wid = img.getIconWidth();
        hei = img.getIconHeight();
        frm.add(new ImagePanel(img));
        frm.setSize(wid, hei);
        frm.setVisible(true);
        setPzImage();
    }

    protected void setPzImage() {
        int sectwid, secthei;
        sectwid = wid/5;
        secthei = hei/5;

        for(int a=0; a<5; a++)
            for(int b=0; b<5; b++)
                piece[a][b]=new ImageIcon(robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(b*sectwid, a*secthei, sectwid, secthei)));

    }
}

class ImagePanel extends JPanel{

    ImageIcon img;
    Dimension section;

    protected ImagePanel(String img_path) {
        img = new ImageIcon(img_path);
        setPanel();
    }

    protected ImagePanel(ImageIcon img) {
        this.img = img;
        setPanel();
    }

    protected void setPanel() {
        section = new Dimension(img.getIconWidth(), img.getIconHeight());
        add(new JLabel(img));
        setPreferredSize(section);
        setMaximumSize(section);
        setMinimumSize(section);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

1. I am making a class that separating image.

Comment: what's the error ?

Comment: It's because constructor of a Robot class can throw an exception, which you are not able to handle in this context. You can potentially instantiate the robot in the PzImage constructor and handle exception in try/catch there.

Comment: *`Robot robot = new Robot(); //under line at "new Robot();"`* Hover over the underlined part, or (not sure about Eclipse) the marker to the left of it to see the cause of the compilation error. You will need to learn how to fix compilation errors. As programmers, we see lots of them!

Comment: I saw that marker but there is no suggestion available there